Printing PDF on default PDF viewer in a chrome extension's side panel closes all chrome windows
In a Chrome extension using a side panel, clicking the print button of the default chrome PDF viewer within the panel causes all Chrome windows to close (possibly all Chrome processes as well). This issue does not occur in a popup or a new tab. Furthermore, no print preview is displayed, and Chrome closes abruptly after about one second.
Screenshot:

manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PDF Print Crash on Side Panel",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "PDF Print Crash on Side Panel",
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidePanel.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "sidePanel.html"
  }
}

sidePanel.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDF Print Crash on Side Panel</title> 
</head>
<body>           
    <iframe src="doc.pdf" style="width:100%;height: 800px;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

service_worker.js:
chrome.sidePanel.setPanelBehavior({ openPanelOnActionClick: true });

You can include a sample doc.pdf file with above files or download all extension files from here
I don't know whether it is a bug or I'm missing something in manifest or something else. Any help will be appreciated.
